# What is the formal definition of addition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone provide a formal definition of addition for the natural numbers directly from the axioms of ZFC? If this can't be done, why not?

Comment: Addition of what?

Comment: Natual numbers. Sorry, meant to type that.

Comment: Among many other places to find this, see Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*.